# Can't connect to any hostnames

Tags: apt, dns

I am trying to install `tasksel` via `apt-get` and then `apt-get install tasksel` but in both of these processes I get errors and it doesn't install.

I have tried pinging the `Ubuntu archives` and common websites like `Google` but that returns error: `unknown host Google.com`

I am connected to my LAN as I am doing these commands through SSH and my LAN has internet connection too. I can also connect to my server via SSH through my domain name/public IP. It seems I can't request connections but only receive them? I don't know :/

I get a bunch of these errors when I try to update:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

(Can't post whole thing as it has more than 10 links)

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected trough SSH, connection has to be working both ways, the problem is somewhere else. You should edit your post including exactly what error you get when you run your command.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just re install my operating system and it seemed to fix it